# named-config with name 'configName' does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, spring-boot

Связка Hibernate + Spring Boot. Что-то я делаю не так. :(
Подробности ниже.

при запуске через mvn clean package выдает:

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.8.RELEASE)

2017-10-26 10:04:15.198  INFO 2936 --- [           main] .g.a.s.SpringBootPostgreApplicationTests : Starting SpringBootPostgreApplicationTests on DESKTOP-N1P2FPC with PID 2936 (started by Nyansus in H:\╤Г╤З╨╡╨▒╨░ ╨╜╨░ H\java-spring-boot\spring-boot-postgre)
2017-10-26 10:04:15.200  INFO 2936 --- [           main] .g.a.s.SpringBootPostgreApplicationTests : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-10-26 10:04:15.240  INFO 2936 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@328cf0e1: startup date [Thu Oct 26 10:04:15 MSK 2017]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
SUREFIRE-859: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/Nyansus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2017-10-26 10:04:16.512  INFO 2936 --- [g-Init-Reporter] com.mchange.v2.log.MLog                  : MLog clients using slf4j logging.
2017-10-26 10:04:16.610  INFO 2936 --- [           main] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry         : Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
2017-10-26 10:04:16.662  WARN 2936 --- [           main] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.C3P0Config       : named-config with name 'configName' does not exist. Using default-config.
2017-10-26 10:04:16.663  WARN 2936 --- [           main] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.C3P0Config       : named-config with name 'configName' does not exist. Using default-config extensions.
2017-10-26 10:04:16.930  WARN 2936 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDaoImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [io/github/aaa4/springbootpostgre/configuration/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
2017-10-26 10:04:16.942  INFO 2936 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-10-26 10:04:16.955 ERROR 2936 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDaoImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [io/github/aaa4/springbootpostgre/configuration/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
```

структура классов

```
maipackage_
         SpringBootApplication-|
          UserConfiguration----|
                               |-controller_| 
                                            |-UserController
                                 |-model__|
                                          |-User
                                          |-UserDao
```

свойства прописаны в application.properties

```
# Thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.cache: false

# Database
db.driver:org.postgresql.Driver
db.url:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring-database
db.username:postgres
db.password:myPass


# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create
entitymanager.packagesToScan: io.github.aaa4.springbootpostgre.model

# c3p0  pooling
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=600

# Logging
logging.file=application.log
```

Подключаю их через @Configuration класс

```
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String DB_DRIVER;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String DB_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String DB_URL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String DB_USERNAME;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

    @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
    private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}")
    private String CONN_POOL_MAX_SIZE;

    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}")
    private String CONN_POOL_MIN_SIZE;

    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}")
    private String CONN_POOL_IDLE_PERIOD;


    @Bean
    public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource("configName");
        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass(DB_DRIVER);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException pve){
            System.out.println("Cannot load datasource driver (" + DB_DRIVER +") : " + pve.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(DB_URL);
        dataSource.setUser(DB_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(CONN_POOL_MIN_SIZE));
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(CONN_POOL_MAX_SIZE));
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(Integer.parseInt(CONN_POOL_IDLE_PERIOD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager =
                new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Моделька User класс

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")

public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

UserDao класс

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void save(User user) {
        getSession().save(user);
    }
}
```

мейн класс

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "io.github.aaa4.springbootpostgre")
public class SpringBootPostgreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootPostgreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: а что надо чтобы выдавало ? в чем вопрос то ?

Comment: Оно не видит конфигурацию прописанную в application.properties

Comment: попробуйте тут и везде в property driver = org.postgresql.Driver (равно поставить) и убрать db.

Comment: @Value("${db.driver}") private String DB_DRIVER; а это тогда не подцепит его

Comment: и тут тоже меняйте..попробуйте..и отпишитесь

Comment: поменял. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
нашел по этому трейсу на большом стеке пост - ругаются на java 9. Добавил ее в зависимости, завалило другими...
разбираюсь